# how to know how many times did the same element in an array appeared after each other?

Tags: java, arrays, dice

I'm trying to figure out how to *count the times that a specific element in an array had appeared after each other*. It's like when throwing a dice how many times did the number 6 appeared after each other.

**For Example:** If this was the result of the throw `56611166626634416` then the result will be 2 times !!

I've already tried to user a for loop and to compare the elements but it keeps on counting if the **6** have appeared more than two times next to each other.

```java
package dice;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class dice2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int k=0;
         Scanner input1 =new Scanner(System.in);
          Scanner input2 =new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("please enter the number of throws!"); 
          int N=input1.nextInt();
          int count=0;
          String faces[]=new String[N];
          System.out.println("enter the faces of the dice !");
         while((N>=1) && (N<= 100) && (N!=count))
         {
            String x=input2.next();
             switch(x) {

             case "1":
                 faces[count]=x;
                 break;

             case "2":
                 faces[count]=x;
                 break;
             case "3":
                 faces[count]=x;
                 break;
             case "4":
                 faces[count]=x;
                 break;
             case "5":
                 faces[count]=x;
                 break;
             case "6":
                 faces[count]=x;
                 break;

                 default : System.out.println(" enter 1-6");
             }
             count++;    
         }

         for(int i=0;i<faces.length;i++) {
              for(int j=i+1;j<faces.length;j++) {     
                  if((faces[i].equals("6")) && (faces[j].equals("6")) )
                  { 
                      k++; i=j; 
                  }
                  else 
                      break;
              }
         System.out.println("k is "+k);
    }
}
```

Comment: what are these variables named after `k, c`

Comment: Please clarify your question, and better organise your code.

Comment: why is this condition used `(faces[i] == 6) && (faces[j] == 6)`  ?

Comment: Why is the answer to your example '2 times'? Please clarify what you are trying to count: I see '66', '666', '66', and '6' in your list of roll results. So if you are trying to count the number of times that a 6 follows a 6, I would think the answer is 4: once for '66', twice for '666' and once for '66'.

Comment: You mean consecutive 6's for this number the answer should be '3', as `66`,`666` and `66`. Am i right ?

Comment: no it should only count if two 6's where adjacent to each other so if we got 666 it won't count@ZainArshad

Comment: @J_D it's used to check if the adjacent numbers were 6's or not but it fails in the case of having more than two 6's adjacent to each other like this 666 but works with this 66

Comment: @jalynn2 this is the text of the home work ! How many times did it occur in the trial, that exactly two 6s were rolled after each other? For example, in sequence 56611166626634416 it occurred twice, that exactly two 6s were thrown after each other.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the working code that only prints those number that occurred consecutively:

```
public class dice
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String input = "11555677666551189988777"; //suppose you saved input using Scanner.Next() in 'input'
        char[] number = new char[input.length()];  // will hold each distintive number
        int[] occurence = new int[input.length()]; //will hold the occurence of that number
        int j=0, distinct = 0, visited = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length() - 1; i++) 
        { 
        // Counting occurrences of input[i] 
            while (input.charAt(i) == input.charAt(i + 1)) 
            {
                if(i!=0)
                {   
                    if (input.charAt(i) != input.charAt(i - 1))
                    {
                        number[j] = input.charAt(i);
                        distinct++;
                        j++;
                    }
                }
                else    
                {
                    number[j] = input.charAt(i);
                    distinct++;
                    j++;
                }
                i++; 
                if(i + 1 == input.length()) 
                    break; 

            } 

        }

        for(int i = 0; i < distinct; i++)
        {  
            int count = 1;  
            for(j = i+1; j < distinct; j++)
            {  
                if(number[i] == number[j])
                {  
                    count++;  
                    //To avoid counting same element again  
                    occurence[j] = visited;  
                }  
            }  
            if(occurence[i] != visited)  
                occurence[i] = count;  
        }  


        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");  
        System.out.println("         Element    |   Consecutive Occurence");  
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");  
        for(int i = 0; i < distinct; i++)
        {  
            if(occurence[i] != visited)  
                System.out.println("                " + number[i] + "   |   " + occurence[i]);  
        }  
        System.out.printf("\nAll other numbers doesn't Occured Consecutively !!"); 
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
----------------------------------------------
         Element    |   Consecutive Occurence
----------------------------------------------
             6      |      3
             1      |      1
             4      |      1

All other numbers doesn't Occurred Consecutively !!!
```

Hope this is what you want, do tell me if you need something else to do with this.

Comment: this would only count the Consecutive numbers , what i want to do is only count it in if only and only the same number had occurred like a double or Consecutive  to the same number like this 66 and not like this 666

Comment: so you want the count of occurrence of all the number that have occurred 2 times consecutive

Comment: `56611166626634416` this should say ... `6 is 2 times` and `4 is 1 time`... am i right ?

Comment: exactly but the home work is forcing us to only count the 6

Comment: i think that i'm getting close this is the latest thing that i came up with it only captures the 6's if they are alone in the shape of couples like this 66 but still alot of bugs for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
    
    for(int j=1;j<list.size();j++) 
    
    { l1=list.get(i); 
    
    l2=list.get(j);
    if(((l1+l2)%2)!=0)    //used the mod to know if the 6's are next to each other where if we had two 6's next to each other the index would be like 5,6 add them together and perfom a mod it shouldn't equal zero .
                      
    
    {

Comment: Yeah this is a good approach. Let me check I think there will be a bit approvement needed !